# KDE Plasma5 battery not detected, but acpi detects it... help?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, power-management, indicator, battery

Dell Xps 13 running Kubuntu Plasma. Had this same issue on GNOME, and it transferred over to KDE while I was installing it. Battery management in settings only shows it has AC Input (which is when I'm connected to a charger), but shows no battery percentage or status. It's like it doesn't detect a battery at all.

Running `acpi -V` gives me the battery info I want, though.

```
Battery 0: Discharging, 94%, 11:32:29 remaining
Battery 0: design capacity 7894 mAh, last full capacity 5608 mAh = 71%
```

`indicator-power` is installed, and at its latest version.

`upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0` gives me the following information (same when I used `BAT1` instead of `BAT0`):

```
native-path:          (null)
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Wed 31 Dec 1969 07:00:00 PM EST (1580143725 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  unknown
    warning-level:       unknown
    battery-level:       unknown
    icon-name:          '(null)'
```

I tried writing `acpi=force` to `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, but with no avail.

Another fix I tried was `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service &disown`, which displays the following:

```
william@william-XPS-13-9360:~$ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service &disown
[1] 2820
william@william-XPS-13-9360:~$ 
(process:2820): indicator-power-WARNING **: 11:51:30.238: Unable to enumerate UPower devices: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.175" (uid=1000 pid=2820 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicato" label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="EnumerateDevices" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.UPower" (uid=0 pid=1011 comm="/snap/upower/22/usr/libexec/upowerd " label="snap.upower.upowerd (enforce)")
```

I don't really know the contents of the message, tried searching it up, but provided no answers.

If anyone is able to help me with this problem, it would be great. In the meantime, I'll resort to using `acpi -V` to check my battery percentage.

Comment: I have this exact same problem with a Dell Latitude E5440, running Ubuntu 20.04. Any luck resolving it?